# JButton table java

Tags: java, swing, layout, jbutton

I am working with Swing and I created a JFrame in which I put 9 buttons.
But I need to access quickly to these buttons, so I would like to create a table of all my JButtons, where I'll be able to access rapidly the buttons.
But I dont find the syntax to declare it...

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [MiG Layout](http://www.miglayout.com/) to easily place all of your items in your JFrame (not only to place your buttons). It makes the placement of your items much easier with less code.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to use a `GridLayout` and add all your buttons to that container.

[image: Grid Table Demo]

```
public class GridDemo {

    public void showUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Grid \"Table\" Demo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 3));

        for (int i=0; i < 9; i++) {
            frame.add(new JButton("Button " + (i + 1)));
        }

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                GridDemo gridDemo = new GridDemo();
                gridDemo.showUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: With a GridLayout, can I do :
for (i=0, i>..., i++) {
gridelayoutName[i]= ...
...
}
?